# Python - Paginación HTML/JQUERY

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, html5, datatables

Hola amigos y compañeros de la comunidad, estoy tratando de hacer una barra de paginación, el problema radica en que mediante un botón solo consigo imprimir/funcionar la primera pagina **pero no las paginas restantes**.

[image: Navegación]

Este es mi código:

```
<div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {    
        $("#descargar").DataTable({                             
            "lengthChange": true,
            "searching": true,
            "ordering": true,
            "info": true, 
            "autoWidth": false,
            "responsive": true,                                                        
            language: {
                "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
                "zeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
                "info": "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
                "infoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
                "infoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
                "sSearch": "Buscar:",
                "oPaginate": {
                    "sFirst": "Primero",
                    "sLast":"Último",
                    "sNext":"Siguiente",
                    "sPrevious": "Anterior"
                },
                "sProcessing":"Procesando...",
            },      
        }) 
        
        $("#descargar").ready(function() {                        
            $('.fa-binoculars').on('click', function() {                                
                var codigoPartner = $(this).data('codigo-partner');
                                           
                var url_seguimiento = "/seguimiento/" + codigoPartner;                            
                
                window.location.href = url_seguimiento;
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Creo yo que el problema podría radicar en el DataTable pero no estoy seguro. Agradecería mucho su ayuda.